# Primevue Chart Model - reactive data

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I am currently trying to use primevue combo chart but to no avail.
I think I have tried every possible thing i could think of.

So what I am trying to do is get some actual data into this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            chartData: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Dataset 1',
                    borderColor: '#42A5F5',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    fill: false,
                    data: [
                        50,
                        25,
                        12,
                        48,
                        56,
                        76,
                        42
                    ]
                },
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Dataset 2',
                    backgroundColor: '#66BB6A',
                    data: [
                        21,
                        84,
                        24,
                        75,
                        37,
                        65,
                        34
                    ],
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    borderWidth: 2
                },
                {
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Dataset 3',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFA726',
                    data: [
                        41,
                        52,
                        24,
                        74,
                        23,
                        21,
                        32
                    ]
                }]
            },
            chartOptions: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Combo Bar Line Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to get some actual data into here?
I have a vuex store in place, but no matter what I have tried I cannot get the data into the chart.

If you could give me a hint it would be very much appreciated.

brgds,
Thomas